# Imagemagick converted image is blurry

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I m using `ImageMagick` command line utility to convert images. I have a large size say (800x300 px) transparent tif image and I want it to convert it to cmyk tif, but the resulting image is blurry. how can I fix this?

What I have so far is

```
convert.exe sourcefilergb.tif 
-colorspace cmyk  -depth 8 -resize 122x44 -quality 100 
-density 300 -virtual-pixel transparent -background none 
-gravity center -extent 122x44 -compress none destinationcmyk.tif
```

How to rectify my above code so that I could get desired result?

Thanks

Comment: Try playing with the [filter:blur](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/filter/#blur) option.

Comment: @nwellnhof, well my problem is to get rid of blurry image

Comment: If you use values smaller than 1.0 for `filter:blur`, the image will get sharper.

Comment: ImageMagick may not resize well in CMYK. You would be best to resize while still sRGB, extend, then at the very end convert to CMYK. But converting to CMYK using profiles does a better job of color quality that just using -colorspace CMYK. Can you post a link to your TIF file. I can then test things.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably an aliasing issue. Try `-adaptive-resize` instead of `-resize`, as explained [in the docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/). You might also try different resolution and density settings depending on your input.

Answer (score 0):

> However, many filters (even the default filters) can blur images
> slightly.
>
> ...
>
> When enlarging or magnifying an image ["-sample] only performs does [sic] pixel replication... However when shrinking an image "-sample" simply deletes rows and columns of pixels.
>
> http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/